# Odoo: test unique constraint?

Tags: python, unit-testing, odoo, odoo-8, unique-constraint

It looks like Odoo fails at testing unique constraint.

I have added this constraint:

```
_sql_constraints = [(
    'uniq_line',
    'unique(routing_phase_id, project_id)',
    'Phase have to be unique per Routing!')
]
```

Constraint itself works, but running unittest, I can't successfully test it.

I tried this:

```
from psycopg2 import IntegrityError

with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
     self.env['project.routing.line'].create(
        self.project_routing_line_1.copy_data()[0])
```

I get this error, when running test:

```
2016-05-28 13:59:16,575 19786 ERROR pas_test openerp.sql_db: bad query: INSERT INTO "project_routing_line" ("id", "routing_phase_id", "sequence", "next_routing_phase_id", "duration", "project_id", "return_routing_phase_id", "need_approve", "create_uid", "write_uid", "create_date", "write_date") VALUES(nextval('project_routing_line_id_seq'), 1, 5, NULL, 10.0, 5, 3, false, 1, 1, (now() at time zone 'UTC'), (now() at time zone 'UTC')) RETURNING id
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oerp/openerp80/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 234, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "project_routing_line_uniq_line"
DETAIL:  Key (routing_phase_id, project_id)=(1, 5) already exists
```

So I don't get it, test catches IntegrityEror (or it does not?), but Odoo still tries to create record which of course fails. Am I doing something wrong here?

**Update**

I started thinking, maybe because it is SQL constraint, python does not catch such exceptions at right time (like using `assertRaises`) because it happens after all python validations? That would explain why test fails.

Comment: Actually, i don't see the problem here. You got a IntegrityError while trying to create your record. Did i miss something?

Comment: @CZoellner Don't you see that I am using `assertRaises`? Its purpose is to test exceptions and to test it you need to catch it when you expect to get an exception. But in my case `IntegrityError` is not catched (for example, other exceptions are caught fine with `assertRaises`. I actually try to create non unique record, not like I'm doing that unexpectedly.

Comment: Ah, yes i didn't see that.

Answer (score 4):

Encountered this issue myself and found an existing test used by Odoo themselves.

They use a `openerp.tools.mute_logger('openerp.sql_db')` decorator on methods testing that an IntegrityError is raised.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/7682760dcad232829fbb5d4221f66a1ebb9d6c91/openerp/addons/base/tests/test_views.py#L864

I added the decorator to my test method and it worked. I guess the IntegrityError being logged squelches the exception from being raised.